# How to resolve Service Provider in Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.3

I'm trying to better understand how Services Container works in Laravel. So I know that Services are used to have something that you want to use set up by Laravel, right?

I'm trying to make a simple example using LDAP php built-in functions. I have this in my `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('ldap', function() {
        $conn = ldap_connect(env('LDAP_HOST'));
        ldap_bind($conn, env('LDAP_BIND'), env('LDAP_PWD'));
        return $conn;
    });
}
```

Then in my controller I'm trying to `$ldap = resolve('ldap');` but it's not working, it says `resolve`doesn't exist. I already tried with `$this->app->make`. How will I get my LDAP connection back?

Comment: I think you want to use `$this->app->make` and you need to add ldap to your service providers config file `config/app.php`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers

Comment: but isn't this block of code already registering the service provider? AppServicePRovider is already load by default, isn't it?

Comment: That method is for registering the binding with the app instance, It requires that you already have an instance of the service provider. It's hard to explain without looking at the code. In short when Laravel creates the service providers for you during bootstrapping, but you have to tell it which ones to create.

Comment: You mean I should create a new service provider with artisan and put this block of code in the boot method? I don't get it.. I already read this laravel doc serveral times :/

Comment: Sounds like you're not using Laravel 5.3. If you're okay with using the helper functions, just use `app()` instead of `resolve()`.

Comment: I'm using 5.3 indeed

Comment: If you're on 5.3 and you're getting an error saying that the `resolve()` function doesn't exist, then something is very wrong. Does `php artisan --version` agree? Have you tried just using the `app()` helper method?

Comment: actually I'm using lumen

Comment: Lumen does not have the `resolve()` helper function. It only has the `app()` helper function. You can read about resolving services out of the container in the [Lumen documentation here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resolve()` helper method was not added until Laravel 5.3. It sounds like you're not using 5.3.

All the `resolve()` helper method does is call the `app()` helper method, anyway. You can continue to use the `app()` helper method to resolve dependencies out of the container.

```
$ldap = app('ldap');
```

You can also use the `App` facade, if you prefer that method.

```
$ldap = App::make('ldap');
```

You will only be able to use `$this->app->make()` from your controller if you've injected the `Application` container object in which your `ldap` binding was registered.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resolving a class by using the function, I usually prefer injecting it either in the Controller constructor, or on the route function, before any parameters.

```php
class Controller
{
    [...]

    public function __construct(Class $class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function authenticate(Class $class)
    {
        $this->class->foo(); // I work!
        $class->foo();  // I work too, yay!
    }

    [...]
```